# Uisng "go so far as to" with location not thing

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases, grammaticality-in-context

The phrase "go so far as to" say or do something, is common. But if I want to describe extreme distance such as traveling to a distant country. Can I use something like:

> I could not imaging I could go so far as to America

If the above phrase is not correct, can you suggest other phrases.

Comment: It's actually "go so far as (to-infinitive)", not "go so far as to".  Does that help?

Comment: I'm not getting what you mean by (to-infinitive). Can you give an example to clarify? And do you mean I can't use this phrase with location (e.g. far country)?

Comment: Is "go to as far as America" correct?

Comment: "to-infinitive" is the infinitive form of a verb.  "to say", "to eat", "to breathe".  In this form, 'to' is not a preposition, but is part of the verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For going to a location (even metaphorically), you use a slightly different phrase.

> I did not think I would go **as far as** America.
>
> I never thought I would get **as far as** Hollywood.
>
> He'll never go **as far as** he wants in his football career if he doesn't practice the fundamentals more.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase 'go so far as to' must be followed by a verb, e.g. 'say' or 'do'. It cannot be followed by a noun, e.g. 'America'. So you could say:

> I did not think he would go so far as to go to America.

This is a rather clumsy sentence, so, although the meaning might be slightly different, you may prefer to say:

> I did not think he would go as far as America.